# http file upload to disk

Tags: python, http, file-upload, cgi

I am using an HTML input of type file to upload files to my own server. In the Python script on the server I can receive the file and its meta-data (like filename and type) as a FieldStorage object.

I have printed the fields of that object to the HTML page in order to see what they hold. When I let it print filename, type, and file (converted to a string), I get this:

`Filename: Lighthouse.jpg
 Type: image/jpeg
 File: <open file '<fdopen>', mode 'w+b' at 0x04403578>`

I assume that `0x04403578` is the address of the file in the server's memory. But what does `mode 'w+b'` mean? And how can I save that file to disk via Python if I have to support arbitrary filetypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File is just an open file object, like you would get from `open`. `<fdopen>` means it has been converted from a file descriptor. `w+b` means it is open for read and write in binary mode.

You can write it like a normal file i.e.

```
w = open('<filename>','w+b')
w.write(f.read())
```

Comment: It works, I haven't thought it was that easy. However, could you explain what `w+b` means? I understand `w` means write and `b` stands for binary, but is it not just `wb`?

Comment: `w+` means both read and write, whereas `w` doesn't allow reading. You can refer to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) for more info on mode strings.